# Import a SSL Client Certificate into the Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, client, ssl

as an extra layer of security, I want to use client site SSL certificates for authentication on my hidden-service webserver. Within the original Firefox (version 36.0)  this is already working (with tor as socks5 proxy), but when I try to import the client certificate (client.pfx)in TBB, the same way as I did in Firefox, simply nothing happens (he should ask me for the certificate password).   I'm wondering is this a Bug or is it suppose to be like this because client certificates with in the Browser certificate store are some how a threat to anonymity (witch then needs to be explained, because my Firefox always ask me if i want to sent my client cert)?

I relay would love to use client cert's on my hidden-service because I hate password's. Maybe somebody can give me a hint how I can do this or if this is impossible with the TBB ?

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 amd64
TBB: 4.0.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a known bug.  See: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/14269